# NodeJS nested promise

Tags: node.js, redis, aws-lambda

I have a scenario where I have to get the data from Redis using AWS lambda.

1. Connect to redis
2. Get the data from redis HASH for a key. (Async call to redis)
3. If you get the data from step 2 (it will return an JSON data) then manipulate something in JSON
4. If you get the data from step 2 then call another async API which will get the data from redis and add it to previously received JSON.
5. If any error occurs (reject) in step4 then return the error.
6. If you get the null from the step 2 then get the data from another hash 
   using the same key (Async call to redis)
7. If you get the data from step 6 (it will return an JSON data) then manipulate something in JSON
8. If you get the data from step 6 then call another async API which will get the data from redis and add it to previously received JSON.
9. If any error occurs (reject) in step8 then return the error.
10. Disconnect to redis.

Now I'm not sure to write a clean code nodeJS with these nested and dependent calls.

```
redisConnection.on('connect', function(){ //Step 1
cache.getFromHash(hash1, key) //Step2
.then(data => {
    if(data){
        data.cost = 1000; // step3
        cache.getMultipleFromHash(hash3, keys) //step4
        .then(moredata => {
            data.moredata = moredata;
            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            };
            redisConnection.quit();
            callback(null, response);
        })
        .catch(err => { // step5
            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify({"err": err}),
            };
            redisConnection.quit();
            callback(null, response);
         })
    } else {
        cache.getFromHash(hash2, key) // step6
        .then(defaultData => {
            defaultData.cost = 1000; // step7
            cache.getMultipleFromHash(hash3, keys) //step8
            .then(moreData => {
                data.moreData = moreData;
                const response = {
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                  };
                  redisConnection.quit();
                callback(null, response);
            })
            .catch(err => { // Step 9
                const response = {
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: JSON.stringify({"err": err}),
                };
                redisConnection.quit();
                callback(null, response);
             })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify({"err": err}),
            };
            redisConnection.quit();
            callback(null, response);
        })
    }
})
.catch(err => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({"err": err}),
    };
    redisConnection.quit();
    callback(null, response);
})
})
```

In this code we can see:
1. Step 3 & 7 - repeated steps
2. Step 4 & 8 - repeated steps
3. Multiple catch blockes
4. Multiple return and close connection.

If I write the same code in sync programming then it will be something like this (hypothetical):

```
   redisConnection.on('connect', function(){
    let data = cache.getFromHash(hash1, key)
    if (! data) {
            data = cache.getFromHash(hash2, key)
    }
    let moreData = cache.getMultipleFromHash(hash3, keys)
    data.cost = 1000;
    data.moreData = moreData;
    connection.quit();
    return data;
})
```

Can we make this async code more clear or there is no option?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at `async/await` syntax for `Promise`

Comment: Try using promise chaining in better way.

Comment: Tried async/await & chaining both but still it's not very clean code.

Comment: It's get more complicated when I have to run this in for loop for multiple keys.

Comment: You can check aync(https://caolan.github.io/async/) library and use async function to execute each one by one with invoking next. I believe https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series as function list as Iterable should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
async yourFunction(){
redisConnection.on('connect', function(){ //Step 1
    try{
      let data = await cache.getFromHash(hash1, key) //Step2
      if(data){
        data.cost = 1000;
        let moredata = await cache.getMultipleFromHash(hash3, keys);
        data.moredata = moredata;
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        };
        redisConnection.quit();
        callback(null, response);
      }
      else{
        let defaultData = await cache.getFromHash(hash2, key);
        defaultData.cost = 1000; // step7
        let moreData = await cache.getMultipleFromHash(hash3, keys) //step8
        data.moreData = moreData;
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
          };
          redisConnection.quit();
        callback(null, response);
      }
    }
    catch(error){
      const response = {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify({"err": err}),
      };
      redisConnection.quit();
      callback(null, response);
    }
  }
}

yourFunction().then(result => console.log(result))
```

You can wrap each await in a try catch block, if you want customised error handling.